Are these roof vents placed properly?
I am building a steam room in my home and wanted to install a separate vent for it. When I went up to the roof to research the area, I found the builder installed the vents like this.
I am not a roofing expert by any means, but this worries me in two ways:

They are positioned too closely to the roof's valley, which could cause leaks because of water accumulation.
They are positioned too closely to each other, which would lead them to work less efficiently.

Obviously, the leakage concern worries me more. Is my concern valid? If it is, it it worth moving the vents? The vents are for the side bathroom, the master bathroom, the toilet for the master bathroom, and the dryer. I hardly ever use any of them. To be frank, I'd mostly use the separate vent for the steam room. So if this isn't a big problem, I could just position the steam room vent away from these vents, so that the warm air coming from there is not near a valley.




It seems to me(not a roofer), they are not sealed properly.  Should have the tops and sides sealed so water has to go around them(not under the shingles).  Being close to the valley will depend on wind direction/snow load.

There must be a reason that they're installed there and not along the ridge and evenly distributed, as I'd expect. Without knowing that I'm not sure I can answer. Have a look in your attic and post some (well lit) photos. I do agree that they're too near the valley, but since they're near the top of the valley there's probably little risk of overflow unless you're in a snow climate.

On a shingled roof you won't see where they are sealed. I'd strongly suspect there are not "roof vents" but probably are "duct terminals" - without an interior picture, no way to tell.
